# Better way to split my results from reading file?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split

I have a function that reads through a file, and gathers the results into an array list.
The array list looks like this  (data)

> [12, adam, 1993, 1234, bob, 1992]

I then need to load these details into new objects called patients. This is the current method I have so far for putting each separate array list item into its own patient, yet it keeps bugging me with an error saying I am passing in  String String Int, and it needs to be a String.

s looks like this

> 12, adam, 1993

And this is the code

```
public void loadPatients()throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> data = IO_Support.readData("PatientData.txt");

    System.out.println(data);
    for(String s : data)
    {
        Sytem.out.println(s);
        patientList.add(new Patient(s));
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to push my array list result into a string for passing into the patient object, or should I use a different way to split the string results?

Read data looks like this

```
public static ArrayList<String> readData(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String temp = in.readLine(); 
    while (temp != null)
    {
        data.add(temp);
        temp = in.readLine();   
    }
    in.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the transition from `data` to usable `s` data.  I'd expect, maybe, passing three values from `data` into Patient's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (temp != null)
{
    temp = in.readLine();   
}
```

**First thing**, You are never adding your input to the ArrayList.. This while loop makes no sense.. It is just reading user input, and swallowing it on every occassion..

**Plus**, after seeing your exception, its sure that you are using a `1-arg constructor` of `Patient class` which is not there.. There are only `0-arg constructor` and `2-arg constructor` in `Patient` class.. You need to use them indeed.

See this code in `loadPatient` method.. You need to add a **1-arg constructor** in your **Patient class** to get it compiled..

```
patientList.add(**new Patient(s)**); --> Will not work
```

So, in your Patient class, add: -

```
public Patient(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
```

`this.s` is the instance variable to store `s` that you passed..

Comment: not necessarily true, unless the OP shows `IO_Support.readData(String)` method, you can't just assume he pushes integers to the same list of strings, he might push them as strings

Comment: `error saying I am passing in String String Int, and it needs to be a String.` --  Here is the error.. What do you catch from it??

Comment: my mistake. but the OP should have included the stack trace of the error to make it even clearer. In fact, I do not think the program will compile if integers are pushed in list of strings

Comment: Full error is:
no suitable constructor found for Patient(java.lang.String)
constructor Patient.Patient(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int) is not applicable; (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) Constructor Patient.Patient() is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: it will be hard to tell without looking at `Patient` class

Comment: @Curia.. They why were you hiding this from us?? You should add it in your original post.. And you need to post your Patient class also..

Comment: @Curia.. You can check out my edited post.. And see whether it is useful??

Comment: Sorry copied over my read data while I was still making changes to it.
It does contain `data.add(temp);` to pick up the data.
Cheers for your help, I am rewriting the patient class with the info you have supplied, and for some other reasons as well such as to simplify it.